# NFS mount rootfs issues in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, kernel, mount, nfs

I am working on Powerpc board using kernel 3.10, having issues with mounting rootfs.

Getting issue as below

```
NET: Registered protocol family 17
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Sending DHCP requests .., OK
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 10.162.0.1, my address is 10.162.103.192
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, hwaddr=00:10:ec:00:5c:5b, ipaddr=10.162.103.192, mask=255.255.0.0, gw=10.162.0.1
     host=10.162.103.192, domain=mvista.com, nis-domain=(none)
     bootserver=0.0.0.0, rootserver=10.162.103.21, rootpath=
     nameserver0=10.162.0.5, nameserver1=10.0.0.5
VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem) on device 0:10.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 144K (c0393000 - c03b7000)
nfs: server 10.162.103.21 not responding, still trying
nfs: server 10.162.103.21 not responding, still trying
nfs: server 10.162.103.21 OK
nfs: server 10.162.103.21 OK
nfs: server 10.162.103.21 not responding, still trying

nfs: server 10.162.103.21 OK

nfs: server 10.162.103.21 not responding, still trying
nfs: server 10.162.103.21 not responding, still trying
```

It is stopping here and not responding, giving cmd line arguments as

```
root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=<server ip>:<root path> rw ip=dhcp
```

and not providing any arguments in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf for target setup/mac address.

I had done NFS server setup based on Ubuntu documentation and I tried same setup with other HOst PC, getting same error as above. I confirmed the host setup is fine for NFS server.

Comment: Please reply to the above question.

Comment: This issue is with Mac Controller Driver , part of The board and Protocol used to connect for NFS. Usually NFS Boot uses UDP, but here in this case, changed it to TCP, and so it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved with changes in MAC controller Driver changes, from 100MBPS to 10MBps, and protocol change from UDP to TCP in fs/nfsroot.c and port no used for NFS boot.

--Regards
Satish.G